# Widget integrated going out of its own zone

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I got a main window (Item) with a 640*480 size.

I integrated a custom widget defined in another qml file, its size is 100*100. This item contains a Pathview that only shows 3 items from a list containing a lot of items.

The thing is that when I add my CustomPathView to my main window at coords (0, 0), the PathView goes to the bottom of my main window, displaying 7/8 items... (?!?)
My CustomPathView.qml file starts with :
    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 100

That's why I really don't understand why it is displaying 8 items...

Did I do something wrong ? Do I have to precise to my CustomPathView that he can't go out of its zone (how ?) ?

Thanks in advance for any help about it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the clip property to true.